# How to get the screen size when flutter is placed on the floating window of android?

Tags: flutter, dart, screen-size

How to get the screen size when flutter is placed on the floating window of android? The MediaQuery method can only get the window size, but not the screen size.

Comment: What is the "floating window of android"? Can you better explain the scenario.

Comment: tried `LayoutBuilder`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this article is good to start.

**Flutter on Surface Duo**

Today we are going to get you started with our Surface Duo SDK for Android so that you can adapt your existing applications for dual-screens and the hinge. The sample code demonstrates how Android developers can add the Surface Duo SDK to a project and then access the screen and hinge APIs.

**Step 1. Add the Android dual-screen SDK to your Flutter project**

**Step 2. Add the Platform Channel and native code required to the Android MainActivity**

**Step 3. Add the Platform Channel code to your Flutter application code**

[read more](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/surface-duo/get-started-with-flutter-on-surface-duo/)